# Como fazer um gif de loading em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Galera eu tô com um problema muito besta no meu projeto em HTML, onde eu queria mostrar uma gif de uma página sendo carregada, mas ela fica muito tempo além do que eu informo e com isso, a minha real página não vêm a ser vista.
Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

HTML:

```
</head>
  <body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div style="display:none;" class="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
<header>
```

CSS:

```
/* Center the loader */
.loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

/* Add animation to "page content" */
.animate-bottom {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animatebottom;
  animation-duration: 1s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
  from { bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to { bottom:0px; opacity:1 }
}

@keyframes animatebottom { 
  from{ bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to{ bottom:0; opacity:1 }
}

.myDiv {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

JS:

```
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 30);
}

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Cara já que vc já está usando @keyframes pq vc não controla o tempo por lá? Esse seu loader é estético ou ele é dinâmico e é funcional de verdade?

Comment: Uai, duas propriedades **classe** na mesma tag Html??? Pode isso Arnaldo??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está tentando selecionar elementos que não possuem a `id` indicada, mas sim classes:

```
       ↓
<div class="loader"></div>
                             ↓
<div style="display:none;" class="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">

                     ↓
document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
                     ↓
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
```

> Tem um erro também que é a dupla declaração de `class`. Isso fará com
>   que o segundo seja ignorado. Altere para: `class="myDiv animate-bottom"`, colocando as duas classes na mesma declaração.

Mas, como são elementos únicos, mude os `class` para `id` no HTML:

```
<div id="loader"></div>
<div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
```

E no CSS também troque o `.` por `#`:

```
↓
#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

↓    
#myDiv {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**Veja:**

```js
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 2000); // aumentei o tempo para ilustração
}

function showPage() {
   document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

/* Add animation to "page content" */
.animate-bottom {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animatebottom;
  animation-duration: 1s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
  from { bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to { bottom:0px; opacity:1 }
}

@keyframes animatebottom { 
  from{ bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to{ bottom:0; opacity:1 }
}

#myDiv {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">
<div id="loader"></div>
<div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
```

> Ou você pode simplesmente selecionar os elementos pela classe com
>   `getElementsByClassName`:

```
function showPage() {
   document.getElementsByClassName("loader")[0].style.display = "none";
   document.getElementsByClassName("myDiv")[0].style.display = "block";
}
```

Onde o índice `[0]` quer dizer que esses elementos são os primeiros das classes presentes na página.

Mas eu acho muito mais recomendado neste caso usar `id`s como indiquei no início da resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado resolveu, mas o problema agora é diferente.
1 - a minha gif que havia algo girando saiu, como podemos fazer com que ele volte?
2 - a minha organização está toda cagada, antes estava tudo centralizado no meio da tela e agora está tudo puxado para a esquerda, como posso fazer para voltar?

PS: a única coisa que eu mudei foi onde vc me informou.

Comment: Se tiver feito como falei não tem como dar errado. Execute o código e verá que a animação tá lá. Só que ele some rápido porque esse "30" nesta linha `myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 30);` é mt rápida.

Comment: Mude os `class` que falei pra `id` no HTML e no CSS.

Comment: Achei onde eu tinha errado, agora está aparecendo o GIF, obrigado. Mas ainda assim a minha formatação que estava centralizado está justificada a esquerda, como poderia fazer isso mudar e voltar?

Comment: tem dois `width: 150px;
  height: 150px;` no .loader

Comment: Já consegui resolver, muito obrigado pela grande ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar o .BlockUI do JavaScript , Veja o exemplo

```
if (id > 0) {
    //Bloquei a tela e mostra a mensagem
       $.blockUI({ message: " Carregando informações da base de dados, isso pode demorar alguns segundos... " });

        ChamaCarregaDados(); // depois que carregar todos os dados

     $.unblockUI(); //Desbloquear UI

    }


    -> não esqueça de colocar a biblioteca
    <script src="jquery.blockUI.1.33.js"></script>
```

baixar em 

 https://github.com/lian/javascript-bundle/tree/master/resources/jquery/plugins/blockui/1.33

Exemplo de como fica [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia [edit] a resposta e linkar essa lib que você está usando?

Comment: Coloquei onde você consegue a biblioteca